# Angular filter in Controller not View

Tags: angularjs, filter

I have a filter in a view which works fine:

```
<ng-repeat="order in orders | filter:approved=true"">
```

However I would like this filter in the root controller as non approved objects never to be parsed.
What do I need to get that result?

```
controller('test', function($scope, $filter) { 
  $filter   ?????
```

Answer (score 1):

Usage is:

```
$filter(filterName)(array, expression, comparator)
```

So in your case its:

```
$scope.orders = $filter('filter')($scope.orders, { approved: true})
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter