# Angular filter in controller

Tags: angularjs, filter, firebase, angularfire

Well I know this question has been asked before and already had an answer.
Here it is: [TheQuestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25421108/angular-filter-in-controller-not-view)

Actually it can't work for me and I tried a lot but failed.
This works fine:

```
<ng-repeat="item in myList | filter:item.visible=true ">
```

And I tried this as [TheQuestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25421108/angular-filter-in-controller-not-view) said:

```
$scope.myList = $filter('filter')($scope.myList, { item.visible: true});
```

I also tried this one:

```
var isOpen = function(item) {
  return item.visible == isOpen;
}
$scope.myList = $scope.myList.filter(isOpen);
```

Both of them cannot work for me. Did I miss something?

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/At1PQ9?p=preview)  may help. Please don't undevote it. Thanks.

Comment: After taking a look at the plunker, it seems there is something *special* about the type that `$asArray` returns.  I cannot index into an element in the controller using `$scope.myList[0]`.  So, this seems to be specific to `$firebase`.

Comment: I will study the API for Angularfire. Thanks.